# Best Practices in Retrieving Related Data in a REST API

Tags: iphone, django, json, rest, tastypie

So I have a REST API in which I Have a resource in which other resources are linked to (related models, in programming point of view).

So how I am doing it right now is that whenever I request for a resource, related resources are referenced via URLs ('/related_data/related_data_id/').

However, I worry that, let's say there are 5 related resources to the one I'm retrieving, is that I would perform 5 GET requests. I am writing an iPhone client and I'm wondering if this is how to properly do it using REST (that I'm returning URLs). A sample JSON response is this:

```
{
"meta": {
            "limit": 20, 
            "next": null, 
            "offset": 0, 
            "previous": null, 
            "total_count": 2
        }, 
"objects": [
    {
        "away_team": "/api/team/3/", 
        "country": "/api/country/1/", 
        "event_date": "2011-08-16", 
        "event_time": "06:00:00", 
        "event_timezone": "GMT", 
        "home_team": "/api/team/4/", 
        "id": "1", 
        "level": "/api/level/4/", 
        "resource_uri": "/api/event/1/", 
        "tournament": "/api/tournament/1/"
    }, 
    {
        "away_team": "/api/team/4/", 
        "country": "/api/country/1/", 
        "event_date": "2011-09-29", 
        "event_time": "12:00:00", 
        "event_timezone": "UTC", 
        "home_team": "/api/team/3/", 
        "id": "2", 
        "level": "/api/level/1/", 
        "resource_uri": "/api/event/2/", 
        "tournament": "/api/tournament/6/"
    }
]
}
```

Is this a proper way of doing it in REST, considering that "each URI must map to a resource" and all those things?

I am using Django and django-tastypie

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; that is proper if the related resources are updated independently. REST architectures depend on caching for performance, and therefore work best with resources which act as atomic entities (see [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668126/should-web-services-be-transactional/6668295#6668295)). That way, you can update resource B and have its representation be fresh without having to update resource A. See [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409877/url-design-for-an-api/4411929#4411929) for more design details.